# querySelector is only working on index page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am adding a light mode to my portfolio site but I am having difficulty toggling all of the elements on some pages. All the query selectors work on the about page(index.html), but none of the others are working.

The basic file structure is:

```
index.html
->pages
   -blog.html
   -contact.html
   -projects.html
->scripts
   -main.js
   -blog.js
   -contact.js
   -light.js
   -projects.js
->css
   -all my stylesheets
```

The bottom of my index.html looks like this:

```html
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/light.js"></script>
</body>
```

and the top:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/light.css" />
```

the other 3 pages are set up like this:

```html
    <script src="../scripts/blog.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/light.js"></script>
</body>
```

and up top:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/projects.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/light.css" />
```

All of the file paths look good to me, and I double-checked the light-mode styling using dev tools by manually typing in `light-mode` in the class name and it worked fine.

My light mode function:

```js
function lightMode() {
  // All
  document.body.classList.toggle('light-mode')
  document.querySelector('.fa-sun').classList.toggle('fa-moon')
  document.querySelectorAll('.line').forEach(line => line.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document
    .querySelectorAll('.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1619735001 .shape-fill')
    .forEach(shape => shape.classList.toggle('light-mode'))

  // About
  document.querySelectorAll('.about-p').forEach(p => p.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document.querySelectorAll('.p-icon').forEach(icon => icon.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document.querySelectorAll('.bullet').forEach(bullet => bullet.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document.querySelectorAll('.tech-used-link').forEach(link => link.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document.querySelectorAll('.tech-used-list').forEach(list => list.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document.querySelector('.paragraph .about-header').classList.toggle('light-mode')
  document.querySelector('.paragraph .working-on-header').classList.toggle('light-mode')
  document.querySelector('.hire-me .tooltip').classList.toggle('light-mode')

  // Blog
  document.querySelectorAll('.devArticle').forEach(blog => blog.classList.toggle('light-mode'))

  // Projects
  document.querySelectorAll('.project-tile').forEach(tile => tile.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document.querySelectorAll('.project-image').forEach(image => image.classList.toggle('light-mode'))

  // Contact
  document.querySelectorAll('.contact-label').forEach(label => label.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document.querySelectorAll('.contact-input').forEach(input => input.classList.toggle('light-mode'))
  document.querySelector('.contact-textarea').classList.toggle('light-mode')
  document.querySelector('.form-submit').classList.toggle('light-mode')
}
```

Everything in the **All** and **About** sections work, but not the last 3 sections.

The light mode toggle is a button in my navbar:

```html
<li><button class="mode-toggle">
 <a class="sun" aria-label="Dark/Light Mode Button" onclick="lightMode()">
  <i alt="sun icon" class="fas fa-sun fa-2x"></i></a>
</button></li>
```

The sections that are in all of the pages like the headers, footers, etc all change, but the specific ones I made for the blog, projects, and contact are not. I feel like I am missing something minor but I've looked at this code too long now to see it ‍

Comment: Are the last 3 sections in the HTML or are they loaded dynamically?

Comment: Why are you adding `light-mode` to every element? Why not just put it on `body` and then use selectors like `body.light-mode .about-p` in the CSS file?

Comment: I was just adding light-mode to every element because I didn't know any better lol, but thank you very much, using body.light-mode on everything and removing all of the query selectors did the trick! Now I just need to have it remember if it was in light or dark mode when you switch pages. I'm guessing I will use local storage for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Barmar, I didn't need all of the query selectors. Instead of adding the light-mode class to each element, I used `body.light-mode .element` for everything.